# VBA AutoFilter filtering out rows outside of set range

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I've got a worksheet that has a section of rows in the middle of it that blank cells are filtered out using AutoFilter successfully using a range to specify which rows to filter out as per below

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$48:$B$507")
    .Autofilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
End With
```

The problem I've run into is that its filtering rows 508:535 which have text in column A that needs to be showing after the filtered data above is shown on the sheet.  Is there something that needs to be added to the above code, or something else new that needs to be added to have the text block appear correctly?

Comment: First, remove the filter from row `508` with `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False`.

Comment: The behaviour has nothing to do with VBA, this is how Autofilter works. No matter what range you specify, the autofilter is applied to the continuous range. If you try highlighting A48:B507 and apply the filter manually, you will get the same behaviour. You will need to either have a blank row after 507, or you will need to enter some filler text in B508:B535 so that they don't get filtered. Suggest something like a space or whitespace character, or format them so that the text is not visible.